# Error 2003: Setting up MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

Trying to setup MySQL Replication using this guide here : http://wpguru.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-setup-mysql-masterslave-replication-with-existing-data/ I was able to do this on two random VMs running the same version of MySQL and it worked perfectly fine. I am trying to do this in a production environment and it doesn't seem to be working. The Slave is unable to connect to the master even though I can connect just fine using the mysql client.

```
140821 11:53:11 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'repl@<host-ip>:7' - retry-time: 3306  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2003
```

The Slave is running `5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` and the Master Server is running `5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log`. I can telnet from the slave to the master. I can also connect using `mysql -u repl -p -h <master-host-ip>` just fine. I am currently stuck at this point and out of ideas.

Comment: Try the usual root causes of Error 2003 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Comment: Hey @RolandoMySQLDBA I went through most of the list and that doesn't seem to have fixed anything. I can log into the replication user from the remote machine, but the slave wont connect still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The slave was trying to connect to port 7 instead of port 3306 for some reason. I had to manually specify that as part of `CHANGE MASTER TO` command and add `MASTER_PORT=3306` and it works perfectly now.